# Get text from Textbox in GTK+

Tags: c++, gtk

I'm trying to `get the input text` from a text box in a `callback function` when the user changes something it it (on `"changed"`).

The code goes as follow:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
void enter_callback( GtkWidget *widget, GtkEditable *buffer)
{
  printf("%s",gtk_editable_get_chars(buffer, 0, -1));
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    GtkWidget *window;
    GtkWidget *text;
    GtkWidget *table;

    gtk_init (&argc, &argv);
    window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    table = gtk_table_new (2, 2, TRUE);
    gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (window), table);
    text=gtk_text_new(NULL, NULL);
    gtk_text_set_editable(text, TRUE);
    gtk_signal_connect(GTK_OBJECT(text), "changed", GTK_SIGNAL_FUNC(enter_callback), (GtkEditable*)text);
    gtk_table_attach_defaults(GTK_TABLE(table), text, 0, 1, 0, 1);
    gtk_container_border_width (GTK_CONTAINER (window), 40);
    gtk_window_set_default_size (GTK_WINDOW(window), 640, 200);

    gtk_widget_show(text);
    gtk_widget_show(window);
    gtk_widget_show(table);

  gtk_main();

  return 0;

}
```

The code compiles just right, I'm compiling it on Code::Blocks on debug, checking output on the console by printf. The problem is I get `<NULL>` as a callback everytime I change something on the textbox. How can I get the correct output?

**SOLUTION:**

As noted by Washu, gtk_text is deprecated and gtk_text_view should be used instead.

Comment: On GTK+ 2.20.1 I have to define GTK_ENABLE_BROKEN for this to compile at all. Also are you sure you are using a C++ compiler? Passing a GtkWidget to text_set_editable() triggers an error when I compile this as C++

Comment: Nope, I don't seem to be getting any warning regarding the compilation of this code. Note however that I'm using GTK+ 2.22.1. I don't know if there's something that changes that much to not throw an error. Deprecated function was probably the problem from the start, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the GTK documentation, GtkText is deprecated, buggy, and should not be used. You should instead be using the GtkTextView widget via gtk_text_view_new.

Comment: Great thanks. I had a hard time going through GTK+ documentation. Although I did read it was deprecated, I couldn't find links to something equal to what I was looking for, and those links that did look like they could help were down (or moved) for some reason.
Will try to rebuild the code for those interested in this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [GtkEntry widget](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/2.99/GtkEntry.html) too. And use gtk_entry_get_text () (which return const gchar *   value) that to get text from GtkEntry, for instance.

Comment: yupp i think using gtk_entry_new() is better than gtk_entry_view_new() with many benefits